# HTML DOCTYPE Syntax error on js files

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have 5 errors on my login page `SyntaxError: syntax error <!DOCTYPE html>` on 5 js files, 
When I checked those files, I found that they are in a non public directory.

How can I ignore these files on Login page or add authorization just for these 5 files ?

Thanks

Comment: How can you add <!DOCTYPE html> in a js file...??

Comment: @PrasathK: It's not a doctype in a js file, the server returns an error page instead of the js file.

Comment: Why are your JS files in a non-public directory?

Comment: How you include your js files to the page? With `ASP.NET` syntax? Or simple `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you could do:

If you need the files on your login-page:

- Move the files to a public folder
- Add a location section to your web.config to make the folder public

If you don't need them on your login-page:

- Make sure you don't reference the files if the user is not authenticated. Example in your view:

  ```
  @{
      if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
          <text><script src="..." /></text>
      }
  }
  ```